# How to understand PySpark fold method

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, pyspark

```
sc.parallelize([2,1,8,5],4).fold(2,lambda a,b:a+1)
sc.parallelize([2,1,8,5],4).fold(2,lambda a,b:b+1)
```

Spark gives 6 for first one and 4 for the second. I am not able to understand these outputs. Below is my intuition for the second example:

Spark divides the data into 4 partitions:

P1 -> [2] 
P2 -> [1] 
P3 -> [8]
P4 -> [5]

Now I apply the lambda function on each partition taking 2 as my zero value for each partition. So a is the zero value and b is the current value in each partition. So now data becomes:

P1 -> [2,2] -> b+1 -> 3 
P2 -> [2,1] -> 2
P3 -> [2,8] -> 9
P4 -> [2,5] -> 6

Now lets do the final combining for all partitions with 2 as zero value:

[2,3,2,9,6] -> [4,2,9,6] (*since a is 2 and b is 3. so b+1 = 4*) ->
 [3,9,6] -> [10,6] -> 
[7]

I am getting 7 as the final answer but spark gives 4. Where am I going wrong? I looked it up online but not able to find an answer.

I tried with multiple examples but my output differs from what Spark gives as an output.

Comment: I can't reproduce your output. When I run `sc.parallelize([2,1,8,5],4).fold(2,lambda a,b:b+1)`, I get `7`

Comment: I am running spark on Cloudera VM running on Python 2.6.6 and Spark 1.6.0. Can versions cause difference in outputs?

Comment: Yes, there might be bug in older version and it got resolved in later versions